# find() method in mongodb returns undefined

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geojson

I am trying to create a route to retrieve the records with nearby location coordinates.
I checked the logs and found the "docs" value as undefined. What am I going wrong with?

```
router.get('/userlist/:lat/:lng', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var lat = req.params.lat, lng = req.params.lng;
    console.log("lat "+lat);
    console.log("lng "+lng);
    var collection = db.get('userlist');
    collection.find({
        "location": {
         $nearSphere: {
           $geometry: {
              type: "Point" ,
              coordinates: [ lat , lng ]
           }
         }
       }
    }, {}, function (e, docs) {      
        docs = JSON.stringify(docs);
        console.log("docs "+docs);
        res.send(docs);        
    });
});
```

I am storing the JSON data as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: I am storing my data as follows]

Comment: Check if you're not making the classic mistake of putting latitude first inside coordinates array, its always [lng,lat] inside coordinates

Comment: @Sarfraaz yes I had put that in correct order only

Comment: `find` returns cursor. Use `.toArray()` to extract the documents. Also check the error part if it has something. `collection.find({
    "location": {
     $nearSphere: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: [ lat , lng ]
       }
     }
   }
}, {}).toArray(function (e, docs) {      
    docs = JSON.stringify(docs);
    console.log("docs "+docs);
    res.send(docs);        
})`

Comment: I am not familairal with the geojson.Problem i can see here is, you are trying to return before you find the collection. You need  to make sync calls . Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ashh I checked and found that toArray() is not available in Mongoose. And I am using Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

The location should be stored in the format:-

```
"location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -70.845654, 
            42.146249
        ]
    }
```

The geojson point should be an object and not an array.

Comment: I am storing it like this:
'location': {
type: "Point", 
coordinates: [
                        $('input#inputUserLocationLng').val(),
                        $('input#inputUserLocationLat').val()
] }

Comment: Formatting should not be an issue. The lat long values are being stored as strings in your data . They should not be enclosed in double quotes as shown in my example.

Comment: They are retrieved from a form. I did a parsefloat for the same.

Comment: But still in the data attached in the question, they are showing as strings

Comment: it's an issue with mongoose

Comment: MongoError: invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ "77.642253", "12.890752" ] }  Point must only contain numeric elements

Comment: This is what I have been telling you till now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206445/discussion-between-anurag-and-webdev).

Answer (score 0):

As @Webdev said, the coordinates are stored as strings and shall not be. But I was unable to store them in numeric form using mongoose. So I am parsing the latitude and the longitude into float in the find query itself and it works.